# How to open a Web Page in Windows Phone 8 and get the HTML?

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone 8 Programming. I have a requirement where I want to load an Web page in Windows Phone 8 and then read its HTML content for Parsing. I am currently using WebBrowser control to navigate to a expected URI, but i am not able to fetch its HTML.

Code -

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://XYZ.com"));
```

**Note: I am not creating any Windows Phone APP. Basically this is a Unit test. And i want to test a website, which can be opened in IE in Windows Phone 8.**

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got a solution, but not sure whether this is the most efficient way.

We need to register a event - LoadCompleted and then we can call the SaveToString() method which stores the HTML of web page in string

Code -

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            string site;
            site = textBox1.Text;
            webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(site, UriKind.Absolute));
            webBrowser1.LoadCompleted += webBrowser1_LoadCompleted;
        });
}

private void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string s = webBrowser1.SaveToString();
        }
```

We can then convert the string to HTML document which should be easy enough.

Answer (score 2):

For just general C#, you can pull the HTML code into a string like this, which you can then parse through:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://XYZ.com");
```

Comment: Thanks MattD for the response!
Actually, my intent is to load the web page in browser and then get the HTML. The above WebClient method will not help. Also just FYI- for windows phone 8 we need to use the async way to download HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse as a safe way to test.